# Double class declaration in CSS

Tags: css, duplicates, declaration, inline-code

So, due to two sets of messy procedural code colliding in horrible Lovecraftian horror that I can't do much about, I am forced to deal with a situation where I'm going to have two *seperate* CSS class declarations on the same objects. For example, I might have an end result that looks like...

```
<div class="my_class" class="cuthullus_child_class_that_overwrites_EVERYTHING">
...something goes here, or so I have been told...
</div>
```

I know having multiple declarations like this is bad, but there's not anything I can really do about it at present. However, I **can** control the content of one of those classes, and potentially the order they appear in...

Given this, what effects will the order have on the classes showing/not-showing? Will one overwrite the the other? Will it error out and I'm effectively left with no class? Will they combine as if both were in the same declaration? Or with it simply destroy Dunwich and everything I hold dear?

Edit: Looking into it deeper, it looks like the div will completely refuse to display, but I"m trying to find some way around that if possible.

Comment: why not use `class="someClass anotherClass"`? instead of declaring it twice

Comment: I literally have no choice in the matter. As much as I -want- to, the procedural code I'm forced to work around forces the creation of two different class declarations.

Comment: bit of an oddball that!

Comment: I know, crazy odd. Marc's explanation helped a lot though, and I was able to make stuff work. 

I ended up going the route that resulted in code that looked like
    `<div class="cuthullus_child_class_that_overwrites_EVERYTHING my_class" class="cuthullus_child_class_that_overwrites_EVERYTHING"> ... something goes here ... </div>`

This resulted in the second declaration getting overwritten like he said, but me  not losing the class, but still being able to apply my own overwrites on top of it, and it seems to be working reliably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two class attributes on the same element will break.  The second class will be ignored, see below.

The only alternative is to add an inline style unless you can clean up the code in the first instance.

```css
.my_class {
  color: blue;
}
.alt_class {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_class" class="alt_class">
  ...something goes here, or so I have been told...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for actually reading the question unlike everyone else on here who smooshed the classes together ignoring the fact I said I was forced into the multiple declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Using duplicate attribute class for one element is invalid in HTML.

This is valid when you need to use multiple classes:

```
<div class="firstClass secondClass"></div>
```

The order does not matter, the classes will be targeted equally from HTML but depends on CSS order.
For example:

```
.secondClass{background: salmon}
.firstClass{background: skyblue}
```

`firstClass` will override `secondClass` because it's set after `secondClass`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use just like this:

```
<div class="my_class second_class third_class">
...something goes here, or so I have been told...
</div>
```

Isn't this working for you?! or you're trying to achieve something else?!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use

```
<style>
.parent_class{
 margin:10px;
}

.parent_class.child_class{
margin:20px;
background:red;
}
</style>

<div class="parent_class child_class">
...something goes here, or so I have been told...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you need to put all the classes in one 'class' attribute separated by a single space, otherwise the browser will only take the first one, aka:

```
<div class="my_class cuthullus_child_class_that_overwrites_EVERYTHING">
...something goes here, or so I have been told...
</div>
```

To answer your second question, whichever one comes later in the stylesheet, will overwrite any rule that also exists with the first class, aka:

```
.my_class{
color: red;
}
.cuthullus_child_class_that_overwrites_EVERYTHING{
color: blue;
}
```

The color would be blue. If they were ordered the other way around, the color would be red. If any of the rules contains '!important' it would take precedence.

Also, if there are different rules within the classes, they won't conflict and will all apply, aka:

```
.my_class{
color: red;
}
.cuthullus_child_class_that_overwrites_EVERYTHING{
font-size: 36px;
}
```

The color would be red and the font-size would be 36px.

It is actually common and not problematic to declare more than one class for a single object; as jQuery is often used to add/remove classes based on different events.